# OMS log search doesnot display all the columns present in WADETWEventTable azure diagnostic table

Tags: azure, etw, azure-diagnostics

I have a cusotm event source which has special properties like message, componentName,Priority. 
[The custom etw event source properties gets converted into azure WADETWEventTable table columns] .

My idea is to view logs stored in azure tables by using Microsoft operations management suite (OMS). I can see the logs but it doesn't display all the columns.

But OMS doesnot display these columns. I am using below code/configuration-

```
[EventSource(Name = "CustomEtw.OperationTrace")]
public sealed class CustomEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static CustomEventSource log = new CustomEventSource();    
    #region [Custom Event Source]
    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Info(string message, string componentName, bool priority)
            {
                WriteEvent(1, message, componentName, priority);
            }
    [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Warning)]
    public void Warning(string warningData)
            {
                WriteEvent(2, warningData);

            }
}
```

Above custom event source logs data on to ETW stream and the same is visible on azure diagnostic table i.e.WADETWEventTable. This Azure table has  data in message,ComponentName and Priority columns as well, but OMS doesn't display these columns when we search thru log search.

Please help, am I missing any configuration that need to b done at OMS side?
Why OMS displays only few columns?

Comment: what is this Microsoft operations management suite ? I never heard about it